# Проблема меню на сайте

Tags: wordpress

В меню "услуги, доставка и т д", если нажать на "отзывы" именно в строке меню, то ничего не происходит, а если нажать правым кликом, открыть в новой вкладке, то работает, но только ясное дело, что так не подойдет.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить это.

Ссылка на сайт http://gelios-pnz.ru

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в вашей теме. Она запускает jQuery версии 2 из `themes/twinkle/js/jquery.min.js`, в то время как последняя версия WordPress (а вас установлена именно она, 5.6) запускает jQuery версии 3.

На клик по ссылке установлен обработчик в файле jQuery вашей темы, там-то клик и умирает, перехода не происходит.

Попробуйте установить плагин [Enable jQuery Migrate Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/), но не факт, что это решит проблему.

Ваша тема устарела и несовместима с WordPress 5.6. Теоретически, можно в ней разобраться и отключить запуск jQuery, но надо иметь исходники темы. И это предмет отдельного вопроса.